# Atom Editor - Open File and treeview works not as expected

Tags: atom-editor

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Atom Editor 1.5.3

If I and click on **Open File** I want that the dialog window shows the directory of the current file I am working on. However, it always shows the directory **Recently Used** and I have to click through the folders to get to my project folder. Where can  I change this so that the dialog window starts in my project folder?

Also I noticed that the treeview doesnt change if I work on a specific file. So if I have two projects folders called **Project 1** and **Project 2** and I start with a file from folder **Project 1** then I see the treeview of this folder. However, if I open a file from **Project 2** and work on this file, the treeview of folder **Project 1** remains. How can I make that the treeview always corresponds to the current file I am working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first part of your question, this is a bug in atom for the linux version. Someone has suggested a patch but it seems it has not been accepted yet in the main atom version, even if it seems to work (see the [discussion](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/10526)). The two commits are [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/10526/commits), if you want to try something with them (what would imply something like recompiling atom yourself of course...).

About the second part of the question: I don't think it's possible to let atom switch automatically from a project to another when clicking on a file. But you can use the [project manager package](https://atom.io/packages/project-manager), what will allow you to define projects, and to set a root directory for each project and then switch from a project to another manually. The treeview will then fit with the current project.

Comment: That are bad news. I hope they fix this bug soon. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I hope too. On another hand, if you use the 'project manager' package, you should be less often in the need to open a file with ctrl+o, so the first problem should become less annoying.